# Objective-C: UItableView registerNib. How?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have `UIViewController` and inside of it `UITableView`. When I am registering via registerClass everything works but ignoring what is inside of custom cell: colors, background, subviews, etc (I am subclassing `UITableViewCell`). When I'm registering via registerNib - it crashes with the error message "Could not load NIB in bundle"

Here the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
[self.view addSubview:_pTableView];

[_pTableView registerClass:[Element1Cell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Element1CellID"];
// [_pTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Element1Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Element1CellID"];

}
```

In `- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` this:

```
oCell = [_pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Element1CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

What am I missing? I haven't been doing it on Objective-C for a while.

(Please only write Objective-C answers. No Swift.)

Comment: do u have cell xib? or simply a subclass ? if u have xib then u need to go with registerNib

Comment: have added this reuse identifier in xib ?

Comment: I do not have XIB, just subclassing

Answer (score 2):

The `registerNib` should be used if your custom cell is defined in the Nib/Xib, but if you just subclass custom cell then you must use `registerClass` as you did

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view addSubview:_pTableView];

   [_pTableView registerClass:[Element1Cell class] 
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Element1CellID"];
}
```

but during dequeuing you have to cast returned cell (which is by interface is a base class), like

```
Element1Cell *oCell = (Element1Cell *)[_pTableView 
   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Element1CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to have access to properties/methods declared in custom class interface.

Answer (score 0):

One part of the problem solved - Ignoring of subviews happened because of lifecycle. I've added method that is setting up the cell and all is working now. The solution is:

- In UITableViewCell define settings in layoutSubviews

  ```
  -(void) layoutSubviews {

      [super layoutSubviews];

      [self setBackgroundColor:__COLOR_BLUE];
  }
  ```
- In UItableViewCell define method that will run setup after creating object

  ```
  -(void) mSetup {

      _pButtonAction = [[UIButton alloc] init];
      [_pButtonAction setTitle:@"Element 1 Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_pButtonAction setTitleColor:__COLOR_BLACK forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_pButtonAction setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
      [_pButtonAction setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
      [_pButtonAction setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
      [_pButtonAction setBackgroundColor:__COLOR_WHITE];
      [_pButtonAction setTintColor:__COLOR_WHITE];
      [_pButtonAction addTarget:self action:@selector(mButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [_pButtonAction setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

      [self.contentView addSubview:_pButtonAction];
      [[_pButtonAction.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor] setActive:YES];
      [[_pButtonAction.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor] setActive:YES];
      [[_pButtonAction.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor] setActive:YES];
      [[_pButtonAction.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor] setActive:YES];
  }
  ```
- In UITableView add run the setup function after dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

  ```
  id oCell;
  ...
  oCell = (Element1Cell*)[_pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Element1CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  oCell = [oCell  mSetup];
  ...
  return (UITableViewCell*)oCell;
  ```